# Как экранировать {} при использовании интерполяции?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, в некотором выражении я использую интерполяцию.

Если я хочу {} интерпритировать как часть строки, то что мне делать?

Я пробовал слешами экранировать, но не помогло...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn961160.aspx):

> Чтобы включить в интерполированную строку фигурные скобки («{» или «}»), используйте две фигурные скобки — «{{» или «}}».
>   Дополнительные сведения см в разделе «[Неявные преобразования](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn961160.aspx#Anchor_0)».